# django objects.all queryset doesn't return all objects from database

Tags: django, row, django-queryset

So I'm using inheritance in django with the following classes:

```
class main_menu(node):
    """
    main_menu(node)

    Has no extra fields. All children of the root node must
    be main_menu nodes
    """
    # Required for tree hierarchy to work (db_column='path' for raw queries)
    _path1 = models.CharField(db_column='path', max_length=Global.MAX_FILE_PATH_LENGTH, unique=True);
    main_menu_blah = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='');

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.main_menu_blah;
```

## main_menu

```
class language(main_menu):
    """
    language(main_menu)

    Main menu used specifically for a main menu targetted
    at a speaker of some language.
    """
    # Required for tree hierarchy to work 
    _path2 = models.CharField(db_column='path', max_length=Global.MAX_FILE_PATH_LENGTH, unique=True);
    language_blah = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='');

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.language_blah;
```

## language

```
class language2(language):
    _path3 = models.CharField(db_column='path', max_length=Global.MAX_FILE_PATH_LENGTH, unique=True);
    language_blah2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='');
```

Now, I can insert access all of these models just fine as long. I can also get them using .objects.get(...).

But if I delete a row from a parent class table (such as language which is a parent to language2), then I cannot get() the last row from the language2 table. 
I execute:
    subNode = language2.objects.get(_path3=);

I always get the following error:

DoesNotExist

language2 matching query does not exist.

And I've looked in the database (sqlite) and I can see that the last entry has  in the column _path3.

Furthermore, I can use a raw query (using connection.cursor()) and I can get the last row. But it's only the raw data, and I need a model object. Oh and using .extra() hasn't worked either.

Why can't I get the last row? (until I reboot the server)

Thanks.

EDIT: 
The different "_path*" variables are needed for something else, so an abstract base class will not help in my case, but that's another topic.

As for the db_column='path', I have it that way so that raw queries are more streamlined and I have tried removing that (so that the column is "_path1", "_path2", etc), but the issue still persists. The part that is most confusing is that a raw query works, and restarting the server fixes it (until a new row is inserted, then that last one isn't seen).

EDIT2:
So I discovered what was happening. The important thing I forgot was how each of the tables were tied together.

If I have a base class:
class A

A subclass:
class B (A)

Another subclass:
class C (B)

I have tables linked like so:

A -> B -> C

Lets say I have 2 rows in each table (each one representing a instance of the class):

row 1 A: Name="Gerald" -> B: Age="25" -> C: Gender="Male"
row 2 A: Name="Janet" -> B: Age="24" -> C: Gender="Female"

If row two in table B is deleted, there is a break in the link that points to table C.
So I basically chopped of the torso of the class. 1/3 of the data is missing. And so, django reports it as non-existent.

So, be sure you are careful when deleting entries manually. You shouldn't have this issue with django as it should keep track of all of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that you have two models that are inheriting from other classes and adding their own fields, but they're using the same `db_column`. A cleaner way to achieve this (if you're not directly using `main_menu`) is with an [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Effectively, your `language2` model has these fields:

```
    _path1 = models.CharField(db_column='path', max_length=Global.MAX_FILE_PATH_LENGTH, unique=True)
    _path2 = models.CharField(db_column='path', max_length=Global.MAX_FILE_PATH_LENGTH, unique=True)
    _path3 = models.CharField(db_column='path', max_length=Global.MAX_FILE_PATH_LENGTH, unique=True)
    main_menu_blah = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    language_blah = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    language_blah2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

Also, Python does not require a semicolon at the end of each statement.